# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory does not return same folder for UnitTesting project

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I am a little confused about why **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory** returns different folders based on different project type.

For example, I have a Web project and a service project and when I refer to

```
    ○ AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

It actually returns folder

- Which is at the same level of Bin folder
- Where all the config files are

Which is perfectly fine and thats what I exactly want. However, when the same code is called by a UnitTest Project then **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory** refers to the folder inside the Bin/Debug instead of pointing at the same level of Bin folder. Now, this breaks all my references while running the UnitTests.

- I am not sure why AppDomain points to two completely different location depending on project type
- How can I make the behavior symmetrical across project Type?

Comment: To answer the *why*: it points to two different locations because web applications run through IIS (or a version thereof, for example, express). In that sense, the directory is the *root* of the site. Tests are simple .exe files and are not executed by an external process, so their base directory is the directory they're currently in. Bonus points: Local IIS and IIS express  have different directories as well ;)

Comment: @Rob can you please convert your comments into an answer so that I can mark it as an answer?